# Html/CSS/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, input, colors

I am doing a site where you can write text in input fields, there is also 3 option menus where you can change the text color, background color and font-style.  When I choose options only the background color and the the text color outside the input field change...what am I going to do so it change in the field?

EDIT:
I can now change the background an text color in the input field, but I cannot change the font style...I cant see whats wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Visitkort</title>
 <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='Style.css' /> 
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SkrivUt() {

        
      var foretag = document.getElementById('foretag');
        foretag.value = document.getElementById('foretagText').value;
 var efternamn = document.getElementById('efternamn');
  efternamn.value = document.getElementById('efternamnText').value;
        document.getElementById('fornamnNamn').value = document.getElementById('fornamnNamnText').value;
        document.getElementById('title').value = document.getElementById('titleText').value;
        document.getElementById('telefon').value = document.getElementById('telefonText').value;
        document.getElementById('ePost').value = document.getElementById('epostText').value;
```

```html
.form-style-3{
    max-width: 400px;
 max-height 400px;
  font-family: "Comic Sans MS", cursive, sans-serif;
```

Comment: It'd be easier to answer this if you posted what you have so far.

Comment: Edit it now! :)

Answer (score 3):

Let's say your input field this just `<input></input>`. Then you can use css to style that element and change the text color.

You can access your element with a css selector. You can find out more about selectors here: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

In your example we can simply give the input field an id

```
<input id="example"></input>
```

and your css:

```
#example {
    color: yourcolor;
}
```

If you want to change the style in javascript with:

```
element.style.color = "yourcolor";
```

The element is your input field. You can get it with the method `document.getElementById("example");`

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
;(function() { // String.randColorHex // Returns Hex Color Code
 var a = '0123456789ABCDEF'.split(''),
  b = a.length;
 function mathRand(min, max) { var r = Math.random() * (max - min + 1); return ~~r + ~~min; }
 function randColorHex() {
  var c = mathRand(0, 100) % 2 ? 3 : 6, d = [ '#' ];
  for (var i=0;i<c;i++) d.push(a[mathRand(0, b-1)]);
  return d.join('');
 }
 Object['defineProperty'] && !String.hasOwnProperty('randColorHex')
  ? Object.defineProperty(String, 'randColorHex', { value: randColorHex })
   : String.randColorHex = randColorHex;
})();

var eles = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=text]')
for (var i in eles) {
 var inp = eles[i];
 if (inp instanceof Element) inp.addEventListener('input', function(e) { this.style.color = String.randColorHex(); })
}
```

```css
body { font-size: 24px; }
h1 { margin-bottom: 0; }
.bkg-black { background: black; }
.bkg-green { background: green; }
```

```html
<h1>Color Changing Text!</h1>
<hr />
<input type="text" placeholder="Just start typing!" />
<hr />
<input type="text" placeholder="Just start typing!" class="bkg-black" />
<hr />
<input type="text" placeholder="Just start typing!" class="bkg-green" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can target your input elements by using `document.getElementsByTagName`. Then you have to loop through each of the `input` elements by using a `for loop` to change the `style` of each one.

Here's what I added to your `SkrivUt() function`:

```
var inputEl = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
for (i=0; i < inputEl.length; i++){
    inputEl[i].style.color = document.getElementById('textColor').value;
}
```

Here's the [jsfddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5vpLnk9L/).

Comment: Thank you, this helpt a lot!